# Ajax + Laravel 5.2 + add an attribute to each of the buttons, buttons are generated by @foreach loops

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

My view:

```
@foreach ($social_networks as $social_network)
    {{ $social_network->displayName}}
@endforeach
```

My Controller:

```
$social_networks = DB::table('social_networks')->get();

if(Auth::user()->admin)
{
    return view('adminDashboard')
            ->with('social_networks', $social_networks)
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 9);
}
return view('dashboard')
            ->with('social_networks', $social_networks)
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 9);
```

My route:

```
Route::resource('dashboard','DashboardController');
```

Basically, what i need is, to try and add a url link to each of the buttons that get generated. And each of the buttons link will be different.

I need to add an attribute to each of these buttons. Let's call it data-url. In there I put the URL of the network And I need to attach a handler that fires when the button is clicked so that the URL is followed.

I want to write some JavaScript that attaches to the social buttons. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.social-network').on('click', '.provider-btn', function( e ) { 
        $.ajax({ 
            'url': 'addconnection',
            'data': {
                network: this.data('network')
            },
            'dataType': 'json'
        }).done(function(json) { 
            if (json.status='ok') { 
                window.location = json.url; 
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

And then on the server side, I need a piece of code that will execute and make sure that the response does something like this:

```
function handleAddConnection($network) { 
    $social_network = DB::table('social_networks')->where('name', $network)->first();
    $url = $social_network->apiUrl;
    $response = array('status' => 'ok', 'url' => $url); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same loop, assuming you have a primary index:

```
@foreach($social_networks as $social_network)
    <a href="{{ route('social_network.show', $social_network->id) }}" class="social-network-ajax"> {{ $social_network->displayName }} </a>
@endforeach
```

Then you can define a click handler which will send an ajax request to the server:

```
$('body').on('click', '.social-network-ajax', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the default link from opening

    var $this = $(this); //referencing


    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $this.prop('href')
    }).done(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    }); 
});
```

Of course define your route accordingly:

```
Route::get('social-network/{social_network}', 'SocialNetworkController@show')->name('social_network.show');
```

Or whatever controller method you wish to send it to.

Comment: I have updated my question, could you plz have a look again at it and see if you can help me out! Thanks